# how to find value using key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, element

Hello I am trying to find the values in a dictionary using they keys which is a 2 element tuple.

For example any basic dictionary would look like this:

```
dict = {'dd':1, 'qq':2, 'rr':3}
```

So if I would like to find the value of 'dd' I would simply do:

```
>>>dict['dd']
   1
```

but what if I had a dictionary who's keys were 2 element tuples:

```
dict = {('dd', 'ee'):1, ('qq', 'bb'):2, ('rr', 'nn'):3}
```

Then how can I find the value of 'dd' or 'rr'

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using the dictionary properly. The keys in the dictionary should be in the form that you want to look them up. So unless you are looking up values by tuple `('dd', 'ee')` you should separate out those keys.

If you are forced to start with that dict structure then you can transform into the desired dict using this:

```
d1 = {('dd', 'ee'):1, ('qq', 'bb'):2, ('rr', 'nn'):3}

# creates {'dd': 1, 'ee': 1, 'qq': 2, 'bb': 2, 'rr': 3, 'nn': 3}
d2 = {x:v for k, v in d1.items() for x in k}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to revert to a linear search

```
>>> D = {('dd', 'ee'):1, ('qq', 'bb'):2, ('rr', 'nn'):3}
>>> next(D[k] for k in D if 'dd' in k)
1
```

If you need to do more than one lookup, it's worth building a helper dict as @bcorso suggests

having said that. `dict` is probably the wrong datastructure for whatever problem you are trying to solve

Comment: okay quick question ... how do I get two objects to be a tuple? .. for example x = 'w' and y = 'q' how do I get the tuple ('w','q')?

Comment: @user3029969 `(x, y)`. If you always know (or and construct) the whole tuple, then a `dict` is appropriate. `D[x,y]` works fine

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> d={('dd', 'ee'):1, ('qq', 'bb'):2, ('rr', 'nn'):3, ('kk','rr'):4}
>>> [(t,d[t]) for t in d if 'rr' in t]
[(('kk', 'rr'), 4), (('rr', 'nn'), 3)]
```